Conditional function when using GDAL Raster Calculator within QGIS Graphical Modeler (model designer)
I want to create a Pre-Calculated Value in GDAL Raster Calculator within Graphical Modeller. The function is to convert values below the threshold to become 0, while the other values are remains. The Inputs are Raster layer & Number (threshold).
I try below expression but does not work.
if(('A < '  || @threshold),'A-A','A')


